# How to Redirect Only the Main Root/index.php and not Root/Folder/index.php via RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, indexing

Dear folks, 
Currently a rewrite should redirect

`/index.php` to `/en/home`

And for that this works fine via the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php /en/home [R=301]
```

However, when `/someotherfolder/index.php` is called, even then it redirects to `/en/home` while it should not! How can I hardcode it to ONLY rewrite, on the condition that its the root-index.php file, and not just any index.php file sitting in other deeper folders?

Thanks very much for your suggestions! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working sample, hope this helps.

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite_log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

Alias /dummy.org /tmp/dummy.org

<Directory /tmp/dummy.org>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index.htm /en/somepage [R=301]
</Directory>
```

If I use "http://127.0.0.1/dummy.org/index.htm" it gets rewritten to "http://127.0.0.1/en/somepage"

```
(3) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] strip per-dir prefix: /tmp/dummy.org/index.htm -> index.htm
(3) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] applying pattern '^index.htm' to uri 'index.htm'
(2) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] rewrite 'index.htm' -> '/en/somepage'
(2) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://127.0.0.1/en/somepage
(1) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] escaping http://127.0.0.1/en/somepage for redirect
(1) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] redirect to http://127.0.0.1/en/somepage [REDIRECT/301]
```

If I use "http://127.0.0.1/dummy.org/someotherfolder/index.htm" it doesnt get rewritten

```
(3) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] add path info postfix: /tmp/dummy.org/someotherfolder -> /tmp/dummy.org/someotherfolder/index.htm
(3) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] strip per-dir prefix: /tmp/dummy.org/someotherfolder/index.htm -> someotherfolder/index.htm
(3) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] applying pattern '^index.htm' to uri 'someotherfolder/index.htm'
(1) [perdir /tmp/dummy.org/] pass through /tmp/dummy.org/someotherfolder
```

-Martin

Answer (score 1):

the best to debug RewriteRule, is to turn on logging of the rewrite process.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x>

  ...

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite_log"
  RewriteLogLevel 3

  RewriteRule .....................

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

One question, is the RewriteRule within a VirtualHost section or within a Directory section ?

-Martin

Comment: +1,  its within a directory (shared hosting on plesk without virtual host permissions)

Comment: @Sam Can you please post the directory section (and the alias if you use one). It makes it much simpler to analyse.

Comment: I rephrased my question. Does that help? Thanks!